# How to fetch data/json using callback and with Nodejs and Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, callback

i am beginner in node.js and MySql and don't no how to retrieve data from database to using callback . But i am reading many examples and other tutorials but any one not give me right answer. please suggest me for right approach.

```
i have 2 table 
   1. category
      Field > cat_id, cat_name
   2. pages
      Field > page_id, page_cat_id (foreign key), page_name

and i want category wise page name 
like ...
  category_1 >> 
    page 1
    page 2
    page 3
  category_2 >> 
    page 1
    page 2
    page 3
```

my current code >>

```
app.get('/pageByCategory', function (req, res) {
  function categorys(callback) {
      var query = connection.query("select * from category", function(err, result, fields) {
          for (var index in result)
          {
              pages(result[index].cat_id, function(results) {
                  callback(results);
                  res.end(JSON.stringify(results));
              });
          }
      });
  }

  function pages(cat_id, callback) {
      query("SELECT * FROM pages where category = " + cat_id, function(results) {
          callback(results);
      });
  }
});
```

but this code not working

Comment: first go through https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql . try with a simple join example query by putting it into conn.query().

Comment: Using an ORM is more advisable if it's a new project. One of the most promising ORM for node.js is `sequelize` would suggest you to give it a try. You can find it's documentation at http://docs.sequelizejs.com

Comment: i have change my request plz check and send me suggestion